# Make t() function translate string on template file?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I created a custom page, with my custom module.

#### Hook_Menu

```
$items['registered-products/%'] = array(
    'title' => t('Hello World'), // TRANSLATES FINE
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_product_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'includes/mymodule.product_page.inc',
);
```

#### Template File

I created a template file (.tpl.php) for my custom page, in here I have:

```
<?php print t('hello world'); ?> <!-- DOES NOT TRANSLATE -->
```

#### RESULT

[image]

The `t()` translates in hook_menu, but on the template file it does not.

**What do I have to do so the `t()` works to on template file?**

Comment: Have you actually gone in and translated the word in the system? It won't happen automatically, you actually have to translate it. Some translations are provided by Drupal.org, which is why you're seeing  - None - translated, but the rest needs to be done manually.

Comment: what do you want? Solution for this case or why function t doesn't work on template?

Comment: @Jonh a solution that works on template file.

Comment: @NoSssweat in Drupal 7 each t() invocation might create a seperate entry in the translation table ... did you check that there is no "Hello World" untranslated ?

Comment: @GiorgosK if you are referring to the Translate Interface, [I only see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBOvr.jpg) and when I click edit, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0USV2.jpg).

Comment: @NoSssweat I see ... I suppose than you could call the t function in a preprocess function and then pass the result as variable to the template.

Comment: You can using module [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) and add more text to translate. It's working.

Comment: @Jonh I installed the module, but again only the hook_menu gets overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be solved as soon as the strings are identical.
In the provided code, *hello world* is not equal to *Hello World*.

> Matching strings for translation is case sensitive.

Comment: `<?php print t('Hello World'); ?>` Does not solve it.

Comment: Is the context language for this call to t() German? E.g. access from a /de/node/XX URL?

Comment: It's a custom page, from custom module, as my question mentions. /de/registration-products/{ product_id }

Comment: Could you try this then t('Hello World', array(), array('langcode' => 'de')) inside the tpl file?

Comment: `<?php print t('Hello World', array(), array('langcode' => 'de')) ?>` does translate

Comment: So, you are missing the language context being set properly. You may need to add some preprocessing logic then for your template and try to determine the current active language.

Comment: Is the OP answered? Or does it need rephrasing?

Comment: The problem is the active language itself @StefanosPetrakis - if you look at `t()`, it gets the current language from `$GLOBALS['language']->language` if none is provided. There's nowhere else to get that from, so it looks like something is overriding the real current language code with an inaccurate one before the template is reached

Comment: In that case we need to know how language negotiation works in that system (e.g. URL based) and what kind of interference may be involved that makes it fail to resolve properly.

Comment: @Clive I think you're right. Weird that my `$GLOBALS['language']` and `global $language` contains the language code and it's not an object (when examining from template file). Let me check on a preprocess function...

Comment: @Clive same result, turns out this is a side effect of [Trying to get property of non-object in i18n_langcode()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248212/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-i18n-langcode-line-229-of-i18n-module) a bug created by a poorly coded inherited module. I never got around to fix it, I told another person to fix it, but clearly they forgot.