# Trying to get property of non-object in i18n_langcode() (line 229 of i18n.module) and a bunch of other property of non-object notices

Tags: 7, debugging

Recent logs lies to me.

[image]

[image]

I even did a `dpm($node->title);` with devel and indeed it's there.

I have like 6 pages of these notices that appear per page load. They are all different locations but they all have the same error type, property of non object. Has anyone experienced something like this?

[image]

I don't think it's a hack, at least not a Core hack, cause Core has been updated several times.

Ugh, soo strange.

---

This is hard to debug, here is another example

[image]

As you can see, I created a variable `$test = i18n_language()->language` and xdebug tells me `$test = "en"` yet on line 230 it fails to get the value according to the log.

[image]

Comment: Could it be related somehow to "Menu Block"? Have you seen [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1318210)?

Comment: Just debug it - add a condition to check if node is not an object, and print a debug backtrace when it is. The log messages definitely aren't lying to you, at best PHP is lying to you, but that's quite unlikely

Comment: very odd... wild guess: try directly emptying the cache tables that don't empty with `drush cc all` (like 'cache_field' and 'cache_form'), I find that with weird snags that sometimes helps

Comment: @Clive see my 2nd screenshot lower right corner, xdbug says it is an object.`$node = {stdClass}[48]`

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens might be possible that some of the errors could be coming from that module, we are using it. After disabling Menu Block module, there was still a lot of errors. Switching theme to Bartik, fixes all the errors but 1. So highly likely a contrib module is causing most of the errors. Or perhaps our theme? I'll comment out template.php

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens mystery solved.

Comment: @Clive mystery solved.

Comment: @longboardnode mystery solved.

Comment: I will delete this Q in 24 hrs, seems useless to have this here, the answer is too unique. Thank you all for trying to help.

Comment: Wow! that took some major sleuthing, glad it resolved!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this mystery.

I was able to narrow it down to a bean block in the site's footer. Upon inspecting all of the bean's block display fields

[image]

Disabling this field fixed the issue. Where is it coming from? IDK yet. I will update once I know. Seems like custom module.

**Update**

Yep, turns out Featurette image link is coming from a custom module. Notice the big error in line 24 and line 30.

[image]

More errors here, what a mess!

[image]

Comment: lol @Pierre.Vriens, apparently featurettes is actually [a thing](https://www.google.ca/search?q=featurettes+definition&oq=featurettes+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.6287j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but for us it's just the name of a Bean Block Type. I wasn't the one who came up with the name ;p

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information posed in the question, and your theme switch test- it sounds like you have some custom templates or template.php functions in your theme that call/use a variable (in this case, probably the title field) without first checking if the variable is actually set.

check for any custom php conditionals or processing of your custom fields/entities in your templates.  Ideally, you'll want to wrap any operation that does something with them in a conditional.  For example:

```
if ( array_key_exists('myCustomVariable',$content) && isset($content['myCustomVariable']) ) { 
  print render($content['myCustomVariable'];
}
```

Also worth noting, the *title of your individual node types is **not available** (by default) in the page.tpl.php or html.tpl.php templates* without some modifications and custom hooks in your theme to make the variable available.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but turnout the theme was not the issue.